# XCODE: Label constraints acting weird

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, view, constraints

I have a label with the following constraints:

[image]

It works fine on the iPhone 11, but for iPhone 8 it acts very strange.  When it is an iPhone 8, or phones of that size, I adjust the top constraint constant from 29 to 10, and did the same for the red asterisk label next to it (25 to 6 for that one), but when I run it on smaller phones like iPhone 8, it looks like this:

[image]

I have tried many things to fix this but to no avail.  Here are the constraints for the asterisk, and the view below (the one housing the textfield.  All you can see of it is the black part outside the textfield.)

Asterisk:

[image]

View:

[image]

And just in case, the navigation bar up top:

[image]

The constraints you see for the navigation bar to the name label and name required label are set from each of those labels respectively.  It just appears in the navigation bar constraints because it applies to it.  Like I said, I adjust those constraints when the phone is smaller, but they don't seem to be taking hold.  I adjust the constraints' constants to 10 for the name label and 6 to the name required label (-19 each).  Any help as to why the view still looks weird is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you actually adding a `UINavigationBar` as a subview? Or are you in a navigation controller?

Comment: I actually added as a subview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple tips...

- Take it step-by-step.
- Give your UI elements contrasting background colors to make it easy to see frames
- Use the Preview pane as you work on your layout

So, add your navigation bar and set its constraints:

[image]

Add your Name and its Asterisk labels and set their constraints. Note: constrain the top of the Asterisk label to the top of the Name label to help keep them together:

[image]

Add your name text field and set its constraints:

[image]

Add your Estimated Height and its Asterisk labels:

[image]

Estimated Height text field:

[image]

Keep going, checking the layout in the Preview pane - and running the app to double-check the layout at run-time - adding each element one at a time.

[image]

If the layout suddenly changes, you know you just did something wrong.

Comment: ugh, the issue was my imageview View being constrained to the bottom of the safe area, making everything else come down with it.  Fixed it though.  Thanks